# Create a wrapper for two java classes

Tags: java

In my project I use two Interfaces([Vertex](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.0.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Vertex.html) and [Node](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.4.M06/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html)) already implemented in other libraries. I want to add objects in lists of those two interfaces, so I have to define an interface because they are different type. I though is to create an interface e.g. NodeInterface and the implementations NodeImpl, VertexImpl that are wrappers to the above Interfaces. How can I do this?

Comment: Composition seems to work nicely for wrappers.

Comment: @Smutje It's the first time I confront a situation like this, so I am completely stuck. I don't know how to begin.

Comment: Your solution will depend how or where you will use it.

Comment: My main problem is that I want to have one object type in my code, like NodeInterface, that it will implemented by NodeImp and VertexImpl which are Node and Vertex wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it this is what you want to do:

You already have:

```
public interface Vertex {...}
public interface Node {...}

public class VertexImpl implements Vertex {...}
public class NodeImpl implements Node {...}
```

And this is what you need:

```
public class Wrapper implements Vertex, Node {

private VertexImpl vertexImp;
private NodeImpl nodeImp;

//methods that wrap Vertex and Node implementations' ones
...

}
```

Comment: So you implement 2 interfaces + store values in private fields? ... actually it might work. soz

Comment: @Fazovsky that's the idea. You can create an interface wich extends the other two, like `public interface VertexNode extends Vertex, Node` and then implement it, if needed, so the Wrapper would implement this new interface

Answer (score 0):

```
class NodeInterface implements Vertex , Node
{
}
```

Wouldn't this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have your implementations implement a common (probably empty) interface, let's call it Point:

`public class VertexImpl implements Vertex, Point`

`public class NodeImpl implements Node, Point`

Add them to the same list:

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
points.add(new VertexImpl());
points.add(new NodeImpl());
```

And when you retrieve them from the list, check the type:

```
for(Point point: points) {
        if (point instanceof Node) {
            System.out.println("node");
            // (Node)point
        } else {
            System.out.println("vertex");
            // (Vertex)point
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand he's looking for an implementation of both interfaces in each instance, not one or another